# Wildfly using h2 for datasource instead of driver I specified

Tags: oracle, jdbc, wildfly, datasource, h2

I added ojdbc6.jar driver to Wildfly as a deployment, and created a datasource which uses the ojdbc6.jar driver. This worked and I was able to access the database in my project - displaying info from the database using a servlet.

However when I restarted my computer it no longer worked (but I hadn't changed anything) and was throwing me `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException` even though I am not trying to connect to the h2 database.

So basically Wildfly seems to keep overwriting the setting for my Datasource to use the ojdbc6 driver and changing it to use the h2 driver and I don't know how to stop this.

Can anyone help?
I have seen online for this problem about editing a persistence.xml file but I don't have one.. should I create one?

Comment: When you add/change the datasource, make sure you modify the config file (standalone-*.xml) while Wildfly is **NOT** up & running.

Comment: I’ve done it all through the wildfly admin console (interface), so not manually touching the xml